# VueJS components

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to make use of VueJS components to clean up my scripts. Therefore I have a component for each page I am loading in into Laravel. Everything works fine so far. But I have issues transfering my current script logic to a component.

This is the current script setup importing the to be used components:

**main.js**

```
import HomeView from './components/HomeView.vue';
import IncidentView from './components/IncidentView.vue';

window.app = new Vue({
   el: '.content',

   components: {
       HomeView, IncidentView
   },

   methods: {

       // Init GIS
      init: function() {

          // Initialize GIS Map
         initGISMap(this.$els.map);
      },
    }
(...)
}
```

Key for me is the `window.app = new Vue...` part. I make use of google maps and therefore when the page is loaded it searches for an app.init method. This is part of the script I am loading within the blade template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                @yield('page_title')
                <small>@yield('page_description')</small>
            </h1>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            @if (isset($vueView))
                <component is="{{ $vueView }}">
            @endif
                @yield('content')
            </component>

        </section>
        <!-- /.content -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&libraries=places&callback=app.init" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The individual pages (where I create for each a module in Vue) look like this:

```
@extends('app', ['vueView' => 'home-view'])
@section('page_title', 'title')
@section('page_description', 'title')

@section('content')
content
@endsection
```

By defining the `vueView` variable, the correct module I am importing in my script is used.

The goal is to use `HomeView` component as the main google maps view. And the other components for different pages I load when clicking the corresponding link in my theme. At the end, I do not want to have all VueJS code in one script. Therefore the models.

When I transfer all the content of this current JS file, I get an error complaining that `app.init` is not a function. The component looks like this:

```
<script>
export default {
   data: {
       // SEARCH
       addressComponents: '',
       autocompletePlace: '',
       autocompleteAddress: '',
(...)
}
```

How do I modify my component in a way, that the app.init load would still work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone has already mentioned [GuillaumeLeclerc/vue-google-maps](https://github.com/GuillaumeLeclerc/vue-google-maps) which is available on npm as `vue-google-maps`, but be warned that that version only works with vue 1.x

If you are using v2, look at this great vue2 fork [xkjyeah/vue-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps) - it's available as `vue2-google-maps` on npm.

The API is straightforward and doesn't diverge far from the v1 version, and the repository is much more active than its upsteam counterpart.

It really made my vue map work a lot more painless than rolling my own, which is what I was initially doing.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should use, or at least study the code, of a package that does that.

For example, you can check **vue-google-maps** on Github : https://github.com/GuillaumeLeclerc/vue-google-maps/

It defines a whole lot of Components related to Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you have a Google Maps script which, when loaded, calls window.app.init, right?

Does your Vue component have an init() method (none is shown above)? If there was one, it would need to be at app.methods.init() remember for VueJS, standard callable methods live under methods key.

Alternatively: you don't mention if your app.init is part of the Vue component or not. If its not it would appear that your app.init function is being overridden because you are redefining window.app as your vue component.

Lastly, if your init is part of Vue, is your google maps fn callback calling this init() before the Vue is loaded and therefore no such method exists (yet)?

Comment: Yes. I am importing the Google Maps script and tell it to load the init method on page load via window.app.init call in the script. I have added the init() method which was not shown by accident, but is existing and loads perfectly fine everything related to the map. All the methods are live and working within the method key. The goal is now to refactor the code and as the "main" page that is loaded is containing the map view, I want to create the component that just contains all the stuff needed for this page. Another page will have different content and I want to use different methods there.

Comment: The app.init is not part of the components. These are just looking like described at the moment. Actually the expression `window.app = new Vue` is giving me the headache in terms of how do I use components properly, so when the google maps script is loaded, it finds the right init method.

Comment: So how I would have structured this is to setup the Google maps as a stand-alone JS service, which is called by the Vue itself, possibly in its created() lifecycle callback. You have better control over coordination this way. You don't have to do this, but otherwise you'll have to coordinate the timing of everything such that the Vue component is available before the callback from maps to the vue is made. 

Suggest logging a note to console in the Vue's created() and ready() lifecycle callbacks and doing same in google maps to see if your maps is ready before your vue.

Comment: Also another though: if you are sharing google maps functionality for different vue components, you might consider packing the google maps code as a mixin - functionality that can be shared between vue instances but is declared only once (in the mixin itself) https://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html